# bash script doesn't read pytest files

Tags: bash, directory, pytest, pytest-django

I am writing afew test cases using `pytest` for my django project. I have created an `.ini` file in the root directory as follow:

```
python_files = 
    tests.py
    test_*.py
    *_tests.py
    *_test.py

norecursedirs =
    devops
    docs
    media
    settings
    common
    templates
    
addopts = 
    --maxfail=9999
    --showlocals
    --color=yes
    --runxfail
    --strict-markers
    --durations=30
    -r a
    ; --reuse-db
    --no-migrations
    --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:TerminalPdb
```

and in the main directory created a folder `/devops` and inside a bash file called `backend_tests.sh` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

options+=("--cov")
options+=("--disable-warnings")
echo "launch pytest ${options[@]}"

poetry run pytest "${options[@]}"

if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then exit 1; fi
```

when I run `devops/backend_tests.sh` it shows, **collected 0 items** but when I move `backend_tests.sh` to main directory and run `./backend_tests.sh` it shows **collected 5 items** (which means loading test cases.

Comment: This is expected - `pytest` uses the Python path. You can run `pytest` from the root path in your script, or you can add the root path to the Python path.

Comment: Ah thanks it works now. if you write as an answer Ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no parameters are given to `pytest`, it [discovers tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html) recursively from the current path. So if you want to use the same command, you could just change the path where it is executed:

```bash
pushd <test_path>
poetry run pytest
popd
```

You can also give the tests or test paths [on the command line](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#specifying-which-tests-to-run), so the shortest way would just be:

```bash
poetry run pytest <test_path>
```

(where `<test_path>` in your case could just be `..`)